# Headroom.js and ie9 support

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm using Headroom.js and I need IE9 support. On a website ( http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/ ) is written that I need to use polyfill:

> Browser support
>   Headroom.js is dependent on the following browser APIs:
>
> requestAnimationFrame  classList  Function.prototype.bind
>
> All of these APIs are capable of being polyfilled, so headroom.js can work with
>   less-capable browsers if desired. Check the linked resources above to
>   determine if you must polyfill to achieve your desired level of
>   browser support.

But with these polyfills Headroom still not working in IE9. I'm beginner, and I guess that something is wrong with classList. Because that these classes are not displaying in IE9 :

> classes : {
>     pinned : 'headroom--pinned', 
>     unpinned : 'headroom--unpinned',
>     top : 'headroom--top',
>     notTop : 'headroom--not-top',
>     initial : 'headroom'
>   }

P.s. sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you load the polyfills *before* all other scripts? Do you have an online demo available someplace that we can test directly?

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! Its was very easy. I haven't load the polyfills before all other scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to load all of your polyfills *before* any other scripts. It sounds as though you might be referencing these too late, and thus not properly benefiting from them.

Comment: Jonathan, maybe you can help me, if I need transform:scale with smooth animation for ie9, but transitions is not supported. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @NatSunSurfer Often times it's okay to go *without* the transition. It's usually not an essential feature. That being said, if you absolutely need the transition, you could load a jQuery fallback that uses [`$.fn.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) via conditional comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a cross-browser classlist

https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

Comment: I'm using this cross-browser classlist but classes for header are not displaying in IE9 and Headroom is not working.

Comment: Also needed a polyfill for `requestAnimationFrame` which is available here https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671